# Displaying Only Certain XML data In HTML Page

Tags: html, xml, data-visualization

I'm completely new to website development and I'm learning things on the fly. I am a Sports Information Director at a small university and need some help spicing up our website. For most sports, we use a program called Stat Crew.

Below is an example of the xml data file.

```
<player name="Player 1" checkname="Player 1" uni="00" code="00" pos="G" year="SR" gs="4" gp="5" fgm="21" fga="42" fgm3="2" fga3="6" ftm="17" fta="24" tp="61" oreb="8" dreb="8" treb="16" blk="0" stl="10" ast="28" to="20" pf="10" tf="0" min="128" dq="0"/>
```

My html is already in a tablet format with each "player" having their own table. What I want to do is display season statistics (updated every game of course) without having to update the html manually. Can I set up my page to pull certain data from the XML (fgm, fgm3, etc) and have it automatically go into the designated html table?

I've tried to just read the questions on this site that have to do with XML but, to be honest, It's confusing.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/xmlhttp.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider looking into [XSL Transforms](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/). This will allow you to utilize your XML data and generate the visualization you want with your HTML familiarity.

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses. I think my biggest issue is getting to a more "familiar" and simplified XML. What the program is giving me is very complex and I can't associate it with the answers given.

Comment: Ok. I'm on to something with the XSLT. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it's coming along. Maybe @Lusitanian can recommend a good tutorial.

Comment: Well I hit a barrier. I'm using a WYSIWYG and I don't know how to create an XSL to display on the page